# How to pass an arraylist of arraylist objects in android intent?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, arraylist

Is it possible to pass an arraylist with arraylists of objects through an intent?

If so, how could you do it? Is it still Parcelable.

So I have arraylist of objects that I'm putting into my main array, and I need that data in the next activity or intent.

Thanks!

Comment: Android Intents are not supposed to carry a large amount of data. You could save that array of arrays in somewhere and retrieve them in the second activity.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intent putExtra ArrayList<NameValuePair>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050030/intent-putextra-arraylistnamevaluepair)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Parcelable Problem with array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7166770/android-parcelable-problem-with-array)

Comment: Like I stated, I want to pass an arraylist that has arraylists in it! Those arraylists are object arraylists. So it a single arraylist with arraylists in it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

of course this is totally do able:

create a class which implements Parcelable:

```
public class SampleObject implements Parcelable {

    public String name;

    public SampleObject(){}

    public SampleObject(Parcel source){
        this.name  = source.readString();
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(name);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<SampleObject> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<SampleObject>(){
        @Override
        public SampleObject createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new SampleObject(source);
        }

        @Override
        public SampleObject[] newArray(int size) {
            return new SampleObject[size];
        }
    } ;
}
```

then when creating the Intent pass as parcelable:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewIntent.class);
// pass the list here, im using a new List as a sample
myIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("NAME", new ArrayList<SampleObject>());
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Comment: A similar easy way is to use Serializable - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14333449/passing-data-through-intent-using-serializable

Comment: @DoronYakovlev-Golani correct, you can do this but android recommends Parcelable as it is better for performance. Serializable is slow compared to Parcelable

Comment: I agree that performance wise you are absolutely correct. However from code the simplicity and maintenance perspectives, Serializable has many advantages.

Comment: The example above seems to pass an arraylist of objects. I want to pass an arraylist with arraylists in it.  And those arraylist are object arraylists. Thanks!

Comment: @huey77 can you show me a code sample. And i will update the answer for your needs

Comment: thanks, but I went a different way about handling my situation. Thanks though. @inner_class7